# Are Identification questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions

Lets say that I was looking at a picture from a recent, significant political affair and I noticed a particularly dapper-looking fellow. Given his location in crowd, I believe that it is safe to assume that he is important politically but I can't for the life of me find any information on him. I can provide a very high-quality gigapixel image that should make it easy to identify him for anyone who knows who he is.

My question is are questions along the lines of "Who is this and why are they politically important?" acceptable here?

I was unable to find anything about questions like these in the tour or here on the Meta and I didn't see a tag about them either, which leads me to believe that they may not be. That said, I can't think of anywhere else on SE this would be closer to on topic than here (and it may just be a case of my needing to go somewhere else to find the answer I'm looking for, which is cool).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that would be on-topic.

In fact, we had such a question recently and it did fairly well: [At Trump's inauguration, who was the man in the wheelchair and why is he important?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/14571/11249).

You'll need to provide some context though, such as where the picture was taken etc. Posting *only* a picture with "who is this?" is too broad. The world is a helluva big place!

Comment: Counter-example of a not so well received identification question: [Who is this politician?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14526/who-is-this-politician). The reasons for rejection are likely the very low picture quality and the lack of any usable context.

Comment: @Philipp: actually the picture was of passable quality. The real problem was that no country or even language in which the TV show was in was provided. Or even any justification for the assumption that the person is a politician somewhere...